# Program with a spawned thread panics when optimization enabled

Tags: multithreading, rust

When I use `rustc 1.rs` to compile the following code, it runs endlessly as expected.

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        let a = 2;
        loop {
            a*a;
        }
    }).join();
}
```

A shorter version:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        loop {}
    }).join();
}
```

However, if I use `rustc -O 1.rs` to compile two programs above, they crash:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { repr: Os { code: 0, message: "Success" } }', src/libcore/result.rs:837
stack backtrace:
1:     0x5650bd0acada - std::sys::imp::backtrace::tracing::imp::write::h917062bce4ff48c3
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:42
2:     0x5650bd0b068f - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h0bacac31b5ed1870
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/panicking.rs:247
3:     0x5650bd0aee7c - std::panicking::default_hook::h5897799da33ece67
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/panicking.rs:263
4:     0x5650bd0af4d7 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h109e116a3a861224
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/panicking.rs:451
5:     0x5650bd0af364 - std::panicking::begin_panic::hbb38be1379e09df0
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/panicking.rs:413
6:     0x5650bd0af289 - std::panicking::begin_panic_fmt::h26713cea9bce3ab0
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/panicking.rs:397
7:     0x5650bd0af217 - rust_begin_unwind
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/panicking.rs:373
8:     0x5650bd0e2f3d - core::panicking::panic_fmt::hcfbb59eeb7f27f75
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libcore/panicking.rs:69
9:     0x5650bd0a6e84 - core::result::unwrap_failed::h15a0fc826f4081f4
10:     0x5650bd0b7ffa - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:97
11:     0x5650bd0a6fc1 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::he32a93ebea7bc7ad
12:     0x5650bd0ae6c4 - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::ha102a6120fc52763
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:605
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21
                        at /build/rustc-1.14.0+dfsg1/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84
13:     0x7fc2d0042423 - start_thread
14:     0x7fc2cfb6e9be - __clone
15:                0x0 - <unknown>
```

If I remove all code in the closure, it exits with no error:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    thread::spawn(|| {
    }).join();
}
```

If I add `println!()` in the loop, it works well too:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        loop {
            println!("123")
        }
    }).join();
}
```

I tested this on Rust 1.14 and 1.15, the same problem appears in both.

Is this because I'm using something wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known issue (#28728)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28728). In short, LLVM optimizes away loops that [have no observable side-effects](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28728#issuecomment-144834539):

> The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one
>   of the following:
>
> - terminate
> - make a call to a library I/O function
> - access or modify a volatile object, or
> - perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation

In the cases here, none of these hold, so LLVM removes the loop entirely. However, the Rust compiler has generated code that assumes the loop never returns. This mismatch causes the crash.

Since having an infinite loop with no side-effects is basically useless, this issue is [not of critical priority](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28728#issuecomment-144834431). The Rust team is currently [waiting for LLVM to provide a better solution](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=31217).

As a workaround, you should simply do something inside the loop, which is likely what you want to do anyway ^_^